# rsync - How to exclude one .htaccess but not all of them

Tags: rsync

I have an `rsync` command for copying my files from dev to production.  I don't want to copy the .htaccess file that's in the root of the HTML directory but, I do want to copy the few .htaccess files that are in its sub directories.

I'm using the argument `--exclude .htaccess` which is stopping all of the files from getting copied.  The other arguments I'm including are `-a --recursive --times --perms`.  Is it possible to configure `rsync` to do this?

*Edit:*
Here is my full command:

```
rsync -a --recursive --times --perms \
    --exclude prop_images --exclude tracking --exclude vtours \
    --exclude .htaccess --exclude .htaccess_backup --exclude "*~" \ 
    /home/user/dev_html/* /home/user/public_html/
```

Comment: Funny, using `--exclude '.htaccess'` should be working, if the source directory you're referencing is also the base directory. Try adding the single quotes `'` to the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify `--exclude .htaccess`, you are excluding any path ending in `.htaccess`.

To exclude only the .htaccess at the root of the transfer source, you need to `--exclude /.htaccess`

From the rsync manpage, some further detail and a reference to additional reading:

> - if the pattern starts with a / then it is anchored to a particular spot in the hierarchy of files, otherwise it is matched against the
>     end of the pathname. This is similar to a leading ^ in regular
>     expressions. Thus "/foo" would match a file named "foo" at either the
>     "root of the transfer" (for a global rule) or in the merge-file's
>     directory (for a per-directory rule). An unqualified "foo" would match
>     any file or directory named "foo" anywhere in the tree because the
>     algorithm is applied recursively from the top down; it behaves as if
>     each path component gets a turn at being the end of the file name.
>     Even the unanchored "sub/foo" would match at any point in the
>     hierarchy where a "foo" was found within a directory named "sub". See
>     the section on ANCHORING INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERNS for a full
>     discussion of how to specify a pattern that matches at the root of the
>     transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this option:

```
--exclude 'some/parts/of/path/.htaccess'
```

Globs are also allowed:

```
--exclude 'some/*/of/*/.htaccess'
```